# How to have a dropdown in each of Datatable row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Currently I successfully appear a dropdown result outside the datatable but how to move the dropdown into each of the datatable row? In my case inside Service Catalogue column. I have searching everywhere but not meet as what I want. The current dropdown that outside datatable should not be appear.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table id="bindNewServiceTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Admin Status</th>
            <th class="text-center">Operate Status</th>
            <th class="text-center">Service Catalogue</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#bindNewServiceTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: url_bind,
        crossDomain : true,
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataSrc : "service"
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "admin_status" },
        { data : "operate_status" },
        { data : "id", "className": "text-center",
            render: function(data){
                return createSelect(data);
            }
        },
        { data : "example" },
    ],
});

function createSelect(id){

    $.ajax ({
        url: url_list_cat,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: id,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(response){
            for (var i = 0; i < response.category.length; i++) {
                $("#dropdown").append($("<option>", {
                    response: response.category[i].name,
                    text: response.category[i].name
                }));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the actual string with the HTML that you want inside the datatable field.

So instead of trying to populate the `div` with `id="dropdown"` you would have to do something like this:

```js
function createSelect(id){
    $.ajax ({
        url: url_list_cat,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: id,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(response){
            var select = "<select id='dropdown'>";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.category.length; i++) {
                var val = response.category[i].name
                select += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + response.category[i].name + "</option>";
            }
            select += "</select>"
            return select;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have apply this code at the function but dropdown is still not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this and adjust it to fit your need

```
$('#bindNewServiceTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: url_bind,
        crossDomain : true,
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataSrc : "service"
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "admin_status" },
        { data : "operate_status" },
        { data : "id", "className": "text-center",
            render: function(data){
                return createSelect(data);
            }
        },
        { data : "example" },
    ],
});

function createSelect(id){

   return  $.ajax ({
        url: url_list_cat,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: id,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(response){
        var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                        "id": id,
                       "value": value  //set you select value from response
                    });
            $.each(response, function(key,value){
                        var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                            "text": value.name,
                            "value": value.name
                        });
                        if(value === value.name){.  //compare the value from select with option selected
                            $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                        }
                        $select.append($option);
                    });
                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried but not success, the value with comment `//set you select value from response` I have replace with `response.category.name `

Comment: is your table populated with dropdown menus ?

Comment: what your table look like now?

Comment: yes I want to populate a dropdown menu at every row inside the datatable in Service Catalog column, every row will have their own id's and appoint to same API, when user select the dropdown, the data will read from the API. but current problem the column is blank.

Comment: same as image that is posted early

Comment: add async to the function and await to the ajax call inside and get back to me if that solved the prob

Comment: I got this error msg `DataTables warning: table id=bindNewServiceTable - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0`

Comment: change the `id` in this line `var $select = $("<select></select>", {"id": id,"value": value });` and put any different id and see if the error message goes, also can you show what your response looks like

Comment: maybe we can move this conversation by email since this conversation has take too long